# Continuity Confusion

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I was reading from Introduction to Analysis by Bartle and I read the following theorem about uniform continuity titled "Uniform Continuity Theorem":

"Let $I$ be a closed bounded interval and let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $I$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $I$. "

I know that uniform continuity can be defined as being continuous at every point in the domain. My confusion is coming from "continuous ON $I$". To me, it sounds like when you say a function is "continuous on $I$" it is saying that it is continuous on the entire interval $I$ and therefore uniformly continuous on $I$. However, it seems that the wording of the "Uniform Continuity Theorem" suggests "continuous on" and "uniformly continuous" are different. Could somebody please clarify for me?

Comment: The definitions are different. Not every continuous function is uniformly continuous. Uniform continuity is not defined as being continuous at every point in the domain, that's the definition of continuity.

Comment: You are mistaken. It is **not true** that uniform continuity can be defined as being continuous at every point in the domain.

Comment: You need to reread the definitions. @jon

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I will reread

Comment: If you know the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ formulation of continuity, the difference is that for continuity, $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$ and $x$, whereas for uniform continuity, it only depends on $\epsilon$ and does not depend on $x$ (that's the "uniformity" in the name--same $\delta$ works everywhere). So your theorem really is that "A continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition for continuity of a function $f:X\to\mathbb R$ at a point $x$ where $X\subset\mathbb R$ is:
$$\forall\epsilon>0\quad\exists\delta>0\quad\forall y\in X\quad |x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$
And $f$ is continuous on a set $Y\subset X$ when:
$$\forall x\in Y\quad\forall\epsilon>0\quad\exists\delta>0\quad\forall y\in X\quad |x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$
The definition for uniform continuity on $Y$ is:
$$\forall\epsilon>0\quad\exists\delta>0\quad\forall x\in Y
  \quad\forall y\in X\quad |x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$

There is a subtle difference in the order of the quantifiers between these two. This is the difference between pointwise and uniform continuity and you should carefully study the definitions.

Edit: had my quantifiers in the wrong order

Comment: Continuity is a local property while uniform continuity is a global one.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima oops I managed to write that out wrong. Should be fixed now

Comment: It should be $|f(y) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ rather than $|f(y) - f(x)| < 0$

Comment: Thanks. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

in closed bounded intervals , continuity at $I $ and uniform continuity at $I $ are equivalent. This is not true for other intervals.
For example

$x\mapsto x^2$ is continuous at $[0,+\infty) $ but not uniformly continuous.

$x\mapsto \frac {1}{x} $ is continuous at $(0,1] $ but not UC.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that it is not obvious that the two continuities are equivalent in closed intervals but is a consequence of theorems that closed bounded subsets are compact and functions from compact (metric) spaces are uniformly continuous. This will surely be covered later in the textbook OP has.

Comment: @DanRobertson That is Heine'sTheorem.